# How to specify array fields in app script advanced services to be used in Google DataStudio?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Testing a change in a query in a App Script connector that connects to Google BigQuery, I have initially tried it in the native bigquery connector, using a custom query. One of the new fields I was fetching was an array, which worked graciously in DataStudio (the intention was building a word cloud, but also linking it to the complete string). However, passing the same query to the Google Apps Script connector, when trying to build a chart based on this array field, an error was returned.

Charts with direct bigquery connection
[image]

The same charts, with the same query, but with apps script connector:
[image]

The same inner query is sent back to bigquery. With the direct bigquery connector it properly unnests the words array when referencing it in a chart, but it fails when using the apps script connector.

My question is, is there any sort of configuration I need to do in the apps script code to successfully handle an array field, the same way the direct bigquery connection does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Advanced Services, getSchema also support passing query configuration now. See [implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/advanced-services) for details. Try passing the query configuration instead of building your own schema. That should work with nested and array fields.